# fasttext building error as Python module in Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, fasttext

I have been trying to install fasttext in a docker container. I am getting the same error after trying many pre-installations.

Essentially, I have the same code in windows and I installed via pip in PyCharm. It works without any problem. I thought in Linux based systems, it would be easier. However, I could not get rid of the installation problem.

Here is the error snippet:

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall 
-fPIC -I/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include - 
I/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc - 
I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c 
python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc -o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64- 
3.7/python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.o - 
DVERSION_INFO="0.9.1" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc: In lambda 
function:
python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc:296:35: warning: 
comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int32_t’ {aka 
‘int’} and ‘std::vector<long int>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [- 
 Wsign-compare]
         for (int32_t i = 0; i < vocab_freq.size(); i++) {
                             ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc: In lambda function:
python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc:310:35: warning: 
comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int32_t’ {aka ‘int’} and ‘std::vector<long int>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
         for (int32_t i = 0; i < labels_freq.size(); i++) {
                             ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
The command '/bin/sh -c cd fastText && python setup.py install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My docker container:

```
FROM python:3.7.4
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Install any necessary dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install
RUN apt install -y libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
RUN python -m pip install --user numpy scipy
RUN apt-get install -y  software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential -y gcc-7
RUN apt-get -y install make
RUN apt-get -qq -y install python3-dev
RUN pip3 install pybind11
RUN pip3 install --upgrade cython
RUN git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
RUN cd fastText && python setup.py install
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
```

Am I missing something? The pre-requirements are specified as:

```
 fastText builds on modern Mac OS and Linux distributions. Since it uses C++11 features, it requires a 
 compiler with good C++11 support. You will need Python (version 2.7 or ≥ 3.4), NumPy & SciPy and 
 pybind11.
```

I have tried installing Numpy and sCipy via pip3, various gcc versions, install fasttext via only `pip install fasttext` etc. Nothing worked so far.

Can someone help with this error, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocking error is the following:

`virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory`.

Your RAM memory is not enough for the compilation (see [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/solved-virtual-memory-exhausted-cannot-allocate-memory-4175507767/)).

One useful advice is to [add a swap file](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/).

Comment: I changed my solution instead of going the way of increasing memory. However, It was a useful answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: I use another library, which is called langdetect. It is simple and useful. https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/